# Count of count according to Row

Tags: mysql

Here I'm getting the value of count three rows but I need that rows of count...

but unable to write the query... please help Me....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM sg_examinations e
  JOIN sg_exam_types t
    ON t.id = e.exam_name 
  LEFT 
  JOIN sg_courses c
    ON c.id = e.course_id
 WHERE e.branch_id = 1 
   AND e.academic_year = 2     
 GROUP 
    BY e.exam_name
     , e.course_id
```

Comment: How are you going to know which count relates to which exam_name/course_id combo???!?!?!?!?!?!??!?

Comment: Perhaps you need count(column_name) ? it is not clear what your expected output is, consider detailing your question. Or perhaps select e.exam_name    , e.course_id, count(*)....

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
SELECT e.exam_name, e.course_id, COUNT(*) 
  FROM sg_examinations e
  JOIN sg_exam_types t
    ON t.id = e.exam_name 
  LEFT 
  JOIN sg_courses c
    ON c.id = e.course_id
 WHERE e.branch_id = 1 
   AND e.academic_year = 2     
 GROUP 
    BY e.exam_name, e.course_id
```